# How to connect to google adx seller API without login?

Tags: php, google-ad-exchange

I am working on AdX seller API. I want to pull data from API on daily basis but the issue is it's always shows below screen..
[image]

I want to connect it automatically and pull the all data with it. so Can anybody help me how do I connect automatically with adx seller API. I am using below code..

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller');
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
$client->setAuthConfigFile('../client_secrets.json');
$service = new google_Service_AdExchangeSeller($client);
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    echo 'hi i am in this';
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    exit;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']){
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}
else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
echo pageHeader('Ad Exchange Seller REST API sample');
echo '<div><div class="request">';
if (isset($authUrl)) {
    echo $authUrl;
    echo '<a class="login" href="' . $authUrl . '">Connect Me!</a>';
} 
else {
    echo 'i am in else';
    echo '<a class="logout" href="?logout">Logout</a>';
};
echo '</div>';
if ($client->getAccessToken()) { }
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the code?

Comment: hey @anil kr vijay do u get the solution for this problem ?

Comment: yes I got the solution for this

Comment: @anilkrvijay I need to do this also can you please share what you did to fix it

Comment: @JosephMckenzie I retrieved a refresh token from the API and my issue is resolved